# How do you create an API that connects a form on a site to a CRM using PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, api, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm rather new to Gravity Forms and building API's using PHP. I need to create a script that whenever a Gravity Form is completed the API sends this as JSON data to a POST URL. They gave me the security key name and value, how do I do this using PHP? Do I need Jquery and/or AJAX?

EDIT:

This is what I have so far but I have no idea if I'm on the right path: (I omitted some fields with "X's" due to obvious potential security reasons)

```
<?php

function calculate_signature( $string, $private_key ) {
    $hash = hash_hmac( 'sha1', $string, $private_key, true );
    $sig = rawurlencode( base64_encode( $hash ) );
    return $sig;
}

//set API keys
$api_key = 'XXXXXXX';
$private_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

//set route
$route = '/XXXXXXX.php';

//creating request URL
$expires = strtotime( '+60 mins' );
$string_to_sign = sprintf( '%s:%s:%s:%s', $api_key, 'POST', $route, $expires );
$sig = calculate_signature( $string_to_sign, $private_key );
$url = 'XXXXXXX.com' . $route . '?api_key=' . $api_key . '&signature=' . $sig . '&expires=' . $expires;

// $form = array(
//         array(
//             'title'          => 'API Generated Form',
//             'description'    => 'This is the description for the form generated by the API',
//             'labelPlacement' => 'top_label',
//             'button'         => array(
//                             'type' => 'text'
//             ),
//             'confirmations'  => array(
//                         array(
//                             'id' => 0,
//                             'name' => 'Default Confirmation',
//                             'type' => 'message',
//                             'message' => 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.',
//                             'isDefault' => true,
//                         ),
//             ),
//             'fields'     => array(
//                          array(
//                         'id' => '1',
//                         'label' => 'My Text',
//                         'type'  => 'text'
//                          )
//                     ),
//         ),
// );


$form = array(


            'age' => NULL


);

//json encode array
$form_json = json_encode( $form );

//retrieve data
$response = wp_remote_request( $url, array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $form_json ) );
if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) != 200 || ( empty( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) ) ) ){
    //http request failed
    die( 'There was an error attempting to access the API.' );
}

//result is in the response "body" and is json encoded.
$body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

if( $body['status'] > 202 ){
    $error = $body['response'];

    //form insert failed, get error information
    $error_code     = $error['code'];
    $error_message  = $error['message'];
    $error_data     = isset( $error['data'] ) ? $error['data'] : '';
    $status     = "Code: {$error_code}. Message: {$error_message}. Data: {$error_data}.";
    die( "Could not post forms. {$status}" );
}

$form_id = $body['response'][0];
echo 'The following form id was created: ' . $form_id . '</br>';

?>
```

Comment: "Jquery and/or AJAX?" these are browser technologies, unrelated to PHP directly. Are you really asking how to make a HTTP request using PHP? Try `cURL` in that case - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. I guess maybe the  wp_remote_request function makes HTTP requests as well by the look of it. So you could stick with that. As for whether you're "on the right lines"...well what happens to your code when you run it? Whoever "they" are, they should have told you how they expect to receive this security key - e.g. in the head, or body of the request, in JSON or other format. Check the docs.

Comment: Yes, I am really asking how to make an HTTP request using PHP because I have little to no idea on what I am doing. I've already checked the docs that's why I'm here asking people to help me out understand.

Comment: And what did the docs tell you to do? We don't know how you're supposed to provide those credentials. It's not the same for every API in the world. If you tell us what the HTTP request is supposed to look like, then we can tell you how to write your code to generate the request in the right format.